# Only app-debug apk is generated while build the project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, apk

Currently I am using android studio 2.3.2..
I am facing  an issue that while I run the project it only generate `app-debug.apk` in the project folder..
to run project in normal device, what should I do to generate its 
`app-debug-unaligned.apk`?

I had tried [this](http://entzeroth.com/export-unsigned-apk-android-studio/),but it didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.